# Can't edit out "Dear ..."

Tags: support, edits

I am trying to edit out "Dear Baju" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4174421/84631). But when I click edit, somehow, "Dear Baju" is not there:

[image]

But after saving it's back again:

[image]

Comment: @TimStone, that only talks about the fact that it's stripped out when you edit, not about the fact that when you click save (if that's the only thing you want to edit), it's back again. You have to use a workaround to get rid of it.

Comment: Same goes for @Antony's possible duplicate.

Comment: You submitted the edit without changing anything, so it didn't cause the post body to be regenerated.

Comment: @TimStone, I understand that, but it leads to the strange situation where you **cannot** edit out "Dear ..." without adding "blabla" first and then editing that out again. That's why I tagged the question with "bug".

Comment: See the linked question - the answer being edited predates the change that would've automatically stripped these when they were posted. Also, if you really can't find anything else to edit in a post besides "dear ...", I would find it very hard to lose any sleep over being blocked.

Comment: @Shog9 I am not losing any sleep over it, but in this case there wasn't anything else to edit. It seemed like a bug, so I opened this question. It probably won't happen often, but other people are going to run in to this in the future and it won't be obvious what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I just killed it - it *was* weird, though.

I ended up having to make another edit (inserting 'bla' at the beginning of the post), saving it, then removing the 'bla' again. Ta-da, desired result.

I hope I didn't just mess this up for debugging, though :P